# How to only allow an array to be pushed into an array once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has other arrays in it which have been pushed in. For an example:

```
const Arrays = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [2,1,3] ];
let myArr = [];

Arrays.map(arr => {
  if(myArr.indexOf(arr)){
   return
  }
  myArr.push(arr)
})
```

`const myArr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [2,1,3] ];`

In this array you can see that there are two arrays with the same set of numbers `1`, `2` and `3`. I want to somehow set a condition saying:

If this array already exist then do not add this array in any order again to prevent this from happening. So that when it comes in the loop that this set of numbers comes up again it will just skip over it.

Comment: Can you also edit in your attempt (code) so we can help you alter it?

Comment: By default, two arrays are equal if they have the same elements **in the same order**. You need to develop a strategy to ignore ordering.

Comment: Added in good sir

Comment: @Code-Apprentice not accurate...they are only equal if they reference same  object

Comment: @Code-Apprentice show me how that makes a difference? `[] != []` and `[] !==[]` and `[[]].indexOf([])` is -1

Comment: @charlietfl Note that I deleted my comment. I'm surprised there is no built-in way to compare the contents of two arrays...that seems like it would be very common.

Comment: could you have repeated elements inside your inners arrays? e.g. `[0, 1, 0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `some()` and `every()` methods to check if same array already exists before `push()`.

```js
const myArr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];
let input =  [2,1,3]

function check(oldArr, newArr) {
  return oldArr.some(a => {
    return a.length == newArr.length &&
      a.every(e => newArr.includes(e))
  })
}

if(!check(myArr, input)) myArr.push(input)
console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: Thank you ! that worked just fine, if I could ask does this just go through the array and first check to see if the new array matches any of the arrays length and if it does does that array include every one of those elements, if it does it returns true? Is this correct?

Comment: Its starts looping oldArr or `myArr` in your case and it will exit the loop on first match because its `some` method, and return true/false. Then inside, it first check if the current element in `some` loop is the same length as `newArr`, if its not it will return false but if it is then it will check if every element in current array from `myArr` is also included in `newArr`.

Comment: I would be careful using .includes method, since Internet explorer does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make temp array with `sorted element with joined` and check by `indexOf`

```js
const myArr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [2,1,3],[6,5,4] ];
var newArr = [];
var temp = [];
for(let i in myArr){
  let t = myArr[i].sort().join(",");
  if(temp.indexOf(t) == -1){
    temp.push(t);
    newArr.push(myArr[i]);
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not respect the special case where only two values are in the array and the array has to check against two values in a different count like

```
[1, 1, 2]
```

and

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

which are different arrays.

For a working solution, I suggest to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and count the occurences of same values of the first array and subtract the count of the values for the other arrray.

As result return the check if all elements of the Map are zero.

```js
function compare(a, b) {
    var map = new Map;
    a.forEach(v => map.set(v, (map.get(v) || 0) + 1));
    b.forEach(v => map.set(v, (map.get(v) || 0) - 1));
    return [...map.values()].every(v => !v);
}

var array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]],
    unique = array.reduce((r, a) => (r.some(b => compare(a, b)) || r.push(a), r), []);

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to sort them numerically with .sort() then compare them.